# How to install R package "appnn"?

Tags: r, package, installation

I am trying to install R package `appnn` ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/appnn/index.html))

Based on Page 2 of its [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/appnn/appnn.pdf), I tried but could not find the function `appnn`.

```
> install.packages("appnn")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/appnn_1.0-0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 46576 bytes (45 KB)
downloaded 45 KB

package ‘appnn’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        D:\TEMP\Rtmp61jYaT\downloaded_packages
> sequences <- c('STVIIE','KKSSTT','KYSTVI')
> predictions <- appnn(sequences)
Error: could not find function "appnn"
```

So how to install it?

Comment: I agree it is duplicate. Sorry for that, but should I delete this answer? I was warned when I try to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have successfully installed the package. To *use* the package you need to run

`library(appnn)`

for it to be attached to the search path. Then the functions will work as normal.

Note that you need to run `library()` everytime you start a fresh R session and want to use this package